# Is there a symmetric basis for $\mathbf{Q}(x,y)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, fields

Consider $\mathbf{Q}(x,y)$, the rational functions in $x$ and $y$, as a vector space over $\mathbf{Q}$.

Let $\sigma$ be the map interchanging $x$ and $y$.  Is there a basis for $\mathbf{Q}(x,y)$ which is invariant under $\sigma$?

Motivation:  a negative answer to this question would give a negative answer to [that question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/193446/does-kx-have-a-k-basis-for-every-set-x-without-ac) too.

The obvious way to construct a basis for $\mathbf{Q}(x,y)$ starts from $\{$ monomials$\ /\ $irreducibles$\}$, but then we have to choose one of $1/(x-y)$ and $1/(y-x)$, and a basis can't symmetrically include both.

Comment: I believe that both invariant and skew-invariant subspaces are of countable dimension. Important is that they are equal, hence, a basis exist: $e_i\pm f_i$, where $e_i$ and $f_i$ are some bases for the invariant and skew-invariant parts, respectively (numbered somehow).

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev, that works.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how a negative answer to this would give a negative answer to the linked question.

Comment: @EricWofsey, suppose we have an asymmetric basis $B$ for $Q(x,y)$.  Let $f_i(x,y)$ be a listing of the polynomials in $Q(x,y)$.  Find the first $i$ such that $f_i(x,y) \in (B-\sigma B)\cup(\sigma B-B)$.  If $f_i(x,y) \in B$, choose $x$; otherwise choose $y$.  So from a basis for $Q(x,y)$ we would get a choice function on $\{x,y\}$.

Comment: On the other hand, if $k(\{x_n:n\in\mathbb N\})$ had a symmetric (invariant under all permutations of the indeterminates) basis for every field $k$, this would give a *positive* answer to the linked question.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, I hope to post an answer of that form soon.